# The way of compute $\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log^s(x)}=\frac1{1-s}\log^{1-s}(x)\Big|_2^\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am not sure, how proof this integrate $\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log^s(x)}=\int_2^\infty\frac{\log'(x)}{\log^{s}(x)}=\frac1{1-s}\log^{1-s}(x)\Big|_2^\infty$ without strong intuition and showing the primary function.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Let $$u=log(x)$$

Comment: What base is the logarithm? e ?

Comment: Are you sure the answer isn't

$=\frac{1}{1-s} \ln^{1-s}(x) \vert_{\ln 2}^{\infty}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove it,
note that
$(\log^a(x))'
=a\log^{a-1}(x)(\log'(x))
=\dfrac{a\log^{a-1}(x)}{x}
$.

Therefore
$(\log^{1-s}(x))'
=\dfrac{(1-s)\log^{(1-s)-1}(x)}{x}
=\dfrac{(1-s)\log^{-s}(x)}{x}
$
so
$(\dfrac{\log^{1-s}(x)}{1-s})'
=\dfrac{\log^{-s}(x)}{x}
=\dfrac1{x\log^{s}(x)}
$.